# What a mockery of a country we belong to

Tags: phrases

Can I use this sentence to express "we live in weird country"

Comment: Why do you think that "mockery" and "weird" have similar meanings?

Answer (score 2):

No. *Weird*, in contemporary use, usually means "strange,unusual", which may or may not be pejorative. A *mockery* of some category is an instance of the category worthy of ridicule and contempt; it implies that the instance has deviated severely from its proper nature and is always pejorative.

Comment: If I want to mean "we live in a ridiculous country" will the phrase be acceptable and grammatically accurate?

Comment: *What a mockery of a country* is much more derogatory than *what a ridiculous country*. It depends on what you want to say.